# Flash/SWF Object Affecting Element Padding

Tags: css, flash, swfobject

I've been racking my brain trying to figure this one out as it's been a problem on the past few sites I've worked on (though they haven't gone live yet) and rather than trying to rig up a solution I'd like to try and discover the root of the problem.

Here's the site in question: (URL removed)

Basically I coded this homepage out as plain HTML and then inserted JavaScript and Flash elements as I completed them over time.  When I got to adding the Flash (using SWF Object), I noticed that it had pushed the elements beneath it down roughly 5px, and only in Firefox and Safari (Internet Explorer, oddly enough, isn't affected). Turning off Flash or disabling JavaScript, which also turns the Flash off, removes this extra padding.

Can someone enlighten me as to what is causing this issue?  I don't notice any major JS or CSS errors (other than a few hacks for IE), so I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the whitespace between the DIVs on the page, and try putting the swf object into its own DIV. That way you can control what the page looks like without loading the swf, and it won't affect the other elements when it loads.

Comment: The whitespace between the divs shouldn't have any bearing on the output of the page.  Regardless, I tried that and it didn't work.

The swf object does have it's own div, called "flashReplace".

Comment: But the div is replaced with the object, if you check the DOM after the page loads.

Comment: As much as I don't like it (for the purposes of semantics), nesting worked.  In this instance, I actually just created a new container div and applied my CSS settings to it, then switched the SWF Object ID over to the image for people without Flash.  Cake.

Comment: @Andrew: A piece of example-code would be great to understand what CSS settings you actually applied.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `line-height:0;`  to the div around the flash-swf:

```
<div id="flashDiv" style="line-height:0;">
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting the margin and padding of the object element to 0px

You're using SWFObject 2.0, which does things slightly differently than the SWFObject of old. The old one would plant the embed INSIDE of a target div. The new one seems to actually replace the entire target DIV with an object tag.

Something I don't like, which is why I still use the old SWFObject.

Answer (score 0):

SWFObject inserts an <object> element. Some browsers treat <object> as an inline element, some treat it as a block-level element.

The fix is to use CSS to ensure that objects are always treated as block-level elements:

```
object { display: block; }
```

[See the SWFObject FAQ on the subject.](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/faq#11._How_can_I_avoid_that_extra_whitespace_is_created_underneath)